# Creating Cytoscape.js extensions

Tags: cytoscape.js

Max, I want to update my extension to the new format, but I am running into issues with placement of custom code.  It seems that the extension framework has been updated a lot since I added an extension 4 years ago.  Is there a way to get better documentation on getting started with adding a extension?  I am happy to help write up the documentation if you can help answer some questions that I think would help get people started.  Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that really changed is that the scaffolder creates a webpack project for you.  The extension registering procedure is the same: http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/api

For example, `cytoscape( 'collection', 'fooBar', function(){ return 'baz'; } )` registers eles.fooBar().

I guess the main thing is that there are a lot more files than what the previous scaffolder generated, so it might be harder to find things.  The layout output has lots of files, because it creates a skeleton impl for each of the continuous case and the discrete case.

The scaffolder isn't strictly necessary.  You could use another build system (or none at all) as long as you call `cytoscape()`.  For example, if you only care about publishing to npm for people who use webpack/browserify/rollup, then you could just use cjs `require('cytoscape')` to pull in the peer dependency.  Exporting a register function is nice if you want to allow the client to decide the order of extension registrations with `cytoscape.use(extension)` (or `extension(cytoscape)`).

You're right that there should be some more docs on the output of the scaffolder.  Maybe a summary of the files would suffice.  We could add a tutorial in the blog later if need be.  Both the docs and the blog just use markdown, so the content could go in either place.

Comment: I was thinking the documentation should discuss how to capture events in an extension, how to attach to lifecycle events, etc.  I am relooking at my extension and it has been a hot minute since I made any edits or even built the extension that so much has changed in the Cytoscape.js library.